# Do gcc's __float128 floating point numbers take the current rounding mode into account?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, floating-point

Do the arithmetic operations on gcc's `__float128` floating point numbers take the current rounding mode into account?

For instance, if using the C++11 function `std::fesetenv`, I change the rounding mode to `FE_DOWNWARD`, will results of arithmetic operations on `__float128` be rounded down?

Is this guaranteed by the `__float128` specification?

Comment: What do you see when you test it on your machine?  Does computing `(__float128)1.0 / (__float128)3.0` give different results when you change the rounding mode from roundTowardPositive to roundTowardNegative, for example?

Comment: From the [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libquadmath/), there's at least some evidence of support of rounding modes.  There are changelog entries for making `strtod` support the rounding mode, for example.

Comment: [As I recall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541589/adding-two-floating-point-numbers), gcc doesn't even really support non-default rounding modes with `double`s.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is **guaranteed** that operations on `__float128` take the rounding mode into account.

According to the *GNU C Library* documentation floating-point calculations respect the rounding mode.

According to the *GCC* manual `__float128` is a floating type which supports arithmetic operations as division etc.

From that I deduce, that for operations on `__float128`, the rounding mode **has to be** taken into account.

The *GNU C Library* documentation states:

> **20.6 Rounding Modes**
>
> Floating-point calculations are carried out internally with extra
>   precision, and then rounded to fit into the destination type. This
>   ensures that results are as precise as the input data. IEEE 754
>   defines four possible rounding modes: [...]

*Reference:* http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html

The *GCC* manual states:

> **6.11 Additional Floating Types**
>
> As an extension, GNU C supports additional floating types, __float80
>   and __float128 to support 80-bit (XFmode) and 128-bit (TFmode)
>   floating types. Support for additional types includes the arithmetic
>   operators: add, subtract, multiply, divide; unary arithmetic
>   operators; relational operators; equality operators; [...]

*Reference:* https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html

### Working Example

[Example code and output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56e5c325e32fb22b)

```
__float128 f1=1.0;
__float128 f2=3.0;

char buf[256];

fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

quadmath_snprintf (buf, sizeof buf, "%*.34Qf",10, (f1/f2));
printf ("%s\n", buf);

fesetround(FE_UPWARD);

quadmath_snprintf (buf, sizeof buf, "%*.34Qf",10, (f1/f2));
printf ("%s\n", buf);
```

outputs:

```
0.3333333333333333333333333333333333
0.3333333333333333333333333333333334
```