# Converting a long double to double with upward (or downward) rounding

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Assume that we are working on a platform where the type `long double` has a strictly greater precision than 64 bits. What is the fastest way to convert a given `long double` to an ordinary double-precision number with some prescribed rounding (upward, downward, round-to-nearest, etc.)?

To make the question more precise, let me give a concrete example: Let `N` be a given `long double`, and `M` be the `double` whose value minimizes the (real) value `M - N` such that `M` > `N`. This `M` would be the upward rounded conversion I want to find.

Can I get away with setting the rounding mode of the FP environment appropriately and performing a simple cast (e.g. `(double) N`)?

*Clarification*: You can assume that the platform supports the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754).

Comment: Certainly FP hardware would be faster than any bit manipulation.  Are you looking for a software solution?

Comment: BTW, don't you mean `(double) N)`?

Comment: Your question is platform-specific, but your proposed solution is exactly how I'd go about this task.

Comment: @chux : That is exactly what I meant, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @tmyklebu : You are right, you can assume that the underlying platform supports the IEEE 754 standard. I added this clarification to the question body as well.

Comment: @chux : First of all, I would like to know whether the solution I proposed always works under the stated assumptions (i.e. IEEE 754). I am also interested in a more general software solution. For example, a binary-type search should work, but is probably not optimal.

Comment: If you are working with `gcc` it will, see for example [**Rounding Modes**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html). It may vary by compiler.

Comment: Apart from the answer I have written, I was about to ask a question about “converting from `double` to `float` rounding down in Java”, bearing in mind that Java does not allow to change the rounding mode from the round-to-nearest default. Multiplying by `0x1.ffffff0001p-1` before rounding means that most positive `double`s are converted correctly (to the `float` immediately below them), but finding a sequence of operations that works for all cases may be tricky. In order to convert rounding down from `long double` to `double`, the constant would be `0x1.fffffffffffff8Lp-1`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: In Java, it's better to do the bit-fiddling yourself.  This holds for just about everything the Java designers didn't think about in 1994 or whatever.

Comment: @tmyklebu I have gotten used to bit-fiddle with sequences like `frexp` -> access significand as integer -> `ldexp`, which save me from having to remember exponent biases and usually simplify the case of denormals, but Java does not even appear to have `ldexp` and `frexp`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Correct.  You have to do the bit-fiddling yourself.  I don't even try to write finicky FP code in Java for these sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I get away with setting the rounding mode of the FP environment appropriately and performing a simple cast (e.g. (double) N)?

Yes, as long as the compiler implements the IEEE 754 (most of them do at least roughly). Conversion from one floating-point format to the other is one of the operations to which, according to IEEE 754, the rounding mode should apply. In order to convert from `long double` to `double` up, set the rounding mode to upwards and do the conversion.

In C99, which should be accepted by C++ compilers (I'm not sure a syntax is specified for C++):

```
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
…
fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
double d = (double) ld;
```

PS: you may discover that your compiler does not implement `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` properly. Welcome to the [club](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541589/adding-two-floating-point-numbers).