# pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, c++14, pragma

I tried to slightly modify the example from [the article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feraiseexcept):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main()
{
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    //int r = std::feraiseexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW | FE_DIVBYZERO);
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double result{};
    asm volatile ("fldl %1\n"
                  "fdivl %2\n" : "=%t"(result) : "m"(x), "m"(y) : "memory");
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    int e = std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    if (e & FE_DIVBYZERO) {
        std::cout << "division by zero\n";
    }
    if (e & FE_INEXACT) {
        std::cout << "inexact\n";
    }
    if (e & FE_INVALID) {
        std::cout << "invalid\n";
    }
    if (e & FE_UNDERFLOW) {
        std::cout << "underflow\n";
    }
    if (e & FE_OVERFLOW) {
        std::cout << "overflow\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but I get a warning (for *clang++*, but the same for *G++* too):

```
warning: pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported, ignoring pragma [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
             ^
1 warning generated.
```

[Another article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl) reported, that the pragma is treat the class of so-called *C standard pragmas*, but the former mentioned article does containing the code, which uses the pragma.

Is it allowed to use the pragma in *C++* code? There is `<cfenv>` header in *C++*. It alludes to the fact that this [*Floating-point environment*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) is avaliable to using in *C++*. But [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) reports about implementation dependent nature of the *Floating-point environment*. Is this touches upon *C++*?

Comment: It's not supported in C compilers either (as of 2015). GCC has a file-scope option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541589/adding-two-floating-point-numbers

Comment: In practice, read your compiler documentation about FP environment access. Standardization is rather limited. Not that it really matters here anyway: the moment you wrote `asm` the standard stopped to apply.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq of the compilers I used, IBM, Oracle, and HP all support the FENV_ACCESS pragma, although I haven't tested it in-depth (it wasn't relevant since my code had to be portable to gcc, unfortunately)