# MinGW gcc set fp rounding mode

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, floating-point, mingw

I'm using gcc compiler, and I want to be able to fast change the sse rounding mode. The following code works if compile it under linux:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
unsigned int _mxcsr_up = _MM_MASK_MASK | _MM_ROUND_UP;
unsigned int _mxcsr_down = _MM_MASK_MASK | _MM_ROUND_DOWN;
unsigned int _mxcsr_n = _MM_MASK_MASK;

void round_nearest_mode() {
    asm (
    "ldmxcsr %0" : : "m" (_mxcsr_n)
    );
}

void round_up_mode() {
    asm (
    "ldmxcsr %0" : : "m" (_mxcsr_up)
    );
}

void round_down_mode() {
        asm (
        "ldmxcsr %0" : : "m" (_mxcsr_down)
        );
}
```

But when I compile it under windows using MinGW, the rounding mode is not changed. What is the reason?

Comment: If you are in a hosted environment, t[ry the standard library instead of inline assembly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround)

Comment: @StoryTeller I include <fenv.h> but I can not use its content. I think that the condition '#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_FENV_TR1' does not satisfied, but I don't know why.

Comment: Build your project as C99. Add `-std=c99` to the compiler invocation (or look for the option in the project options if you use an IDE).

Comment: What makes you think the mode is not changed?  How are you testing this?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: I think he really isn't changing rounding mode, because he's ORing the _MM_MASK_MASK instead of ANDing it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Unfortunately, it did not help: https://s21.postimg.org/fds92e91j/image.png

Comment: @PeterCordes Rounding mode is changing. Recursive summation of rounded numbers were performed. Results from linux:   
 rounding down  = 1.04008e-21, rounding up   = 1.04026e-21, exact (multiple-precision) = 1.04017e-21.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Please see my previous comment.

Comment: So you are using `fegetround()` to check the rounding setting?  I believe it uses the `fnstcw` instruction to get its value in mingw.  The value set with the `ldmxcsr` instruction needs to be retrieved via the `stmxcsr` instruction, which (as Peter has mentioned) can be retrieved via `_mm_getcsr()` (and in `fegetenv()` if you check `__unused1`).

Answer (score 1):

The same header that provides the `_MM_ROUND_UP` constants also defines [`_mm_setcsr(unsigned int i)`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LDMXCSR.html) and [`_mm_getcsr(void)`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STMXCSR.html) intrinsic wrappers around the relevant instructions.

You should normally retrieve the old value, OR or ANDN the bit you want to change, then apply the new value.  (e.g. `mxcsr &= ~SOME_BITS`).  You won't find many examples that *just* use LDMXCSR without doing a STMXCSR first.

Oh, I think you're actually doing that part wrong in your code.  I haven't looked at how `_MM_MASK_MASK` is defined, but its name includes the word MASK.  You're ORing it with various other constants, instead of ANDing it.  **You're probably setting the MXCSR to the same value every time, because you're ORing everything with `_MM_MASK_MASK`, which I assume has all the rounding-mode bits set.**

---

As @StoryTeller points out, you don't need inline asm or intrinsics to change rounding modes, since the four rounding modes provided by x86 hardware match the four defined by `fenv.h` in C99: ([`FE_DOWNWARD`, `FE_TONEAREST` (the default), `FE_TOWARDZERO`, and `FE_UPWARD`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round)), which you can set with [`fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround).

If you want to change rounding modes on the fly and make sure the optimizer doesn't reorder any FP ops to a place where the rounding mode was set differently, you need
`#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`, [but gcc doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471254/pragma-stdc-fenv-access-on-is-not-supported).  See also  [this gcc bug from 2008 which is still open: Optimization generates incorrect code with -frounding-math option (#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS not implemented)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34678).

---

Doing it manually with `asm volatile` still won't prevent CSE from thinking `x/y` computed earlier is the same value, though, and not recomputing it after the asm statement.  Unless you use `x` or `y` as a read-write operand for the asm statement that is never actually used.  e.g.

```
asm volatile("" : "+g"(x));  // optimizer must not make any assumptions about x's value.
```

You could put the LDMXCSR inside that same inline-asm statement, to guarantee that the point where the rounding mode changed is also the point where the compiler treats `x` as having changed.