# Why does std::round offer versions returning long and long long while std::floor, std::ceil, std::trunc don't?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking at these related families of standard functions in cppreference: [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), [`std::floor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor), [`std::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) and [`std::trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc).

Is there any reason why `std::round` is the only one providing specific signatures for `long` and `long long` as return type? I am struggling to think of any reason other than historical, but `std::round` has been added fairly recently with C++11.

Comment: [This isn't 100% a duplicate, but it answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605544/8746648). (First google result for "return value of `std::floor`")

Comment: Returning integers doesn't make sense. `std::round` just has it for some reason.

Comment: @asynts it is an intersting read, but it doesn't answer my question, I would image the same restriction highlighted in the question would apply for std::round, but somehow the standard library offers specific functions for it and not for floor.

Comment: In case of `std::floor` the straight up implicit casting does the job. So why write a function that would do it?

Comment: most likely because c had the [exact same set of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round), but it would be interesting to know why c didn't add the `long` / `long long` versions for `ceil` / `floor` / `trunc`.

Comment: @ALX23z And by `std::floor` you mean `std::trunc`, right? :-) The difference is that with casting you can overflow, i.e. UB, and with `std::trunc` you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my guessing but I think the reason might be, that `l` and `ll` versions of `floor`, `ceil` and `trunc` can be realized using [rint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/rint) and different [rounding modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round). For example, `llfloor()` could be implemented like this:

```cpp
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

long long llfloor(double arg) {
    auto save_round = std::fegetround();
    std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    auto ret = llrint(arg);
    std::fesetround(save_round);
    return ret;
}
```

One nice property of `l`/`ll` versions is that they raise [FE_INVALID exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) when the result is outside the range of the result type. Our `llfloor()` does that too:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    double input = std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<long long>::max(), INFINITY);
    std::cout << "input  =  " << std::fixed << input << "\n";

    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    auto result = llfloor(input);
    if (std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)) {
        std::cout <<"FE_INVALID was raised\n";
    }
    std::cout << "result = " << result << "\n";
}
```

and the output is (or see in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vsvW6f9Yq)):

```
input  =  9223372036854777856.000000
FE_INVALID was raised
result = -9223372036854775808
```

You may still be asking "Can't `llround` be implemented with `llrint`?". Turns out it can't. The FE_TONEAREST rounding mode does [rounding to even](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2120) for halfway cases, while `round` does away-from-zero.

Also be aware that the compiler support for accessing or modifying the [floating point environment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) might not be fully there yet:

```
main.cpp:3: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    3 | #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
```

(related question: [Adding two floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541589/adding-two-floating-point-numbers) )